# Manage email messages from the shell

Tags: software-recommendation, email, 16.10

I'd like to manage all my email messages directly from the shell. I'm actually using Thunderbird, but this is not satisfy me perfectly. Could anyone be able to suggest me different ways to treat my messages from the shell?

In fact, I have more than one email address and it is not possible to manage massages for those multiple account in the same time on Thunderbird software.

So two criteria is asked in this question :

1. Manage emails massages directly from the shell.
2. Being in multiple email addresses in the same time.

**Edit :**

I know now Sup-mail would've been a good choice, but it seems there's a blockage (see [''Rats, that failed, you may have to do it manually"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/851269/rats-that-failed-you-may-have-to-do-it-manually)). Could anyone be able to display other choices than Sup or Mutt (which is pretty hard to configure)?

Comment: Thunderbird does have unified folders. Look for them in the view menu. Do they meet your demand?

Answer (score 1):

> Sup is a console-based email client for people with a lot of email.
>
> It presents an interface of a list of threads, which are each
>   hierarchical collections email messages. Threads can have multiple
>   tags applied to them. It supports a very fast full-text search,
>   automatic contact-list management, custom code insertion via a Ruby
>   hook system, and more. If you’re the type of person who treats email
>   as an extension of your long-term memory, Sup is for you.

This might be tool you're looking for...At least it should fulfill your requirements. Not sure tho. :-)

https://github.com/sup-heliotrope/sup

Answer (score 1):

I know this is going back a bit, and a there aren't as many people using it anymore, but one I used to use years ago was Mutt.

From the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mutt)

> Mutt is a powerful command line email client. It supports both mbox and Maildir formats. The protocols supported include POP3 and IMAP. It was originally designed to be a Mail User Agent (MUA) and used to rely on Sendmail but support for sending mail was eventually added.

The feature list is quite long, and has been in development since 2006.

You can find the feature list [here](http://www.mutt.org/)

Excerpt:

- IMAP and POP3 support
- Support for mbox, MMDF, MH, maildir
- Drafts
- Tagging
- Message Header Editing
- PGP Support
- MIME Support

Installation: `sudo apt-get install mutt`

Configuration: `~/.muttrc`

It might suit your needs.  I've never tried to use multiple accounts at the same time though, so I don't know if it will work for your specific situation.

Comment: Ok, could I use a *.outlook.com email address? ... because they talked about Gmail

Comment: Yes, definitely.  What you're seeing is only an example :)