# ''Rats, that failed, you may have to do it manually"

Tags: command-line, gnome, email, 16.10

I'm trying to configure Sup-mail with the command-line `sup-config`, but it failed. I got the message `Rats, that failed, you may have to do it manually`. Could anyone tell me how can I fix this problem?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: would be nice if you provide the output of your terminal as text instead of an image.

Answer (score 2):

> The final step is to import messages into the Sup index.
>   Depending on how many messages are in the sources, this could take a while.

Seems as if sup is installed but was unable to load messages. There is surprisingly little information available on how to do this manually. Try `man /usr/bin/sup-sync` or `/usr/bin/sup-sync --help` and read this - hopefully there are a few answers.

`No such file or directory` indicates that there is a file or directory missing which sup-sync expected to be there. Check those docs or help output, to figure out which locations are involved and check whether or not they are available by the user running `sup-config`.

Additionally I found [this on the ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sup#Crashing_with:_Illegal_instruction_.28core_dumped.29) - can you try to run `sup` or `sup-config` to verify if you ran into that bug? I would start with that step.